# Union star symbol in set theory

Tags: set-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra, semirings

In the slides [Provenance for Database Transformations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eval/EDBTkeynoteLausanne.pdf), page 24, they provide a semiring for lineage, which include a $\cup^*$ symbol. However, I can not find any related materials about the meaning of this symbol. To be more specific, the elements in this semiring should be set of different symbols, e.g, $\{a,b,c\}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can find the paper cited two lines earlier on page 24, that should define $\cup^*$, because it's not a standard set-theoretic notation.  Otherwise, you might ask Tannen by email.

Comment: A wild guess: the bottom of the slide suggests that $\cup$ and $\cup^*$ are operations defining a semiring structure, which in particular means that one distributes over the other. This suggets that $\cup^*$ stands for *intersection*. The slide also seems to be saying that the neutral elements are $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset^*$. So perhaps the author writes $*$ for set-theoretic complement (relative to a ground set), so that $\cup^*$ denotes the de Morgan dual of $\cup$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yeah I checked that paper but didn't find the definition of this symbol. I guess in that paper they define the lineage and Tannen worked on this symbol for the semiring.

Comment: @TobiasFritz I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. In that case, if given a•b, what should it be under ∪∗ operation?

Comment: @BrandNewStory: now I don't know what you mean by $a\bullet b$. All I meant is that $\cup^*$ may stand for the intersection of sets, just as $\cup$ stands for the union of sets. That's my guess.